# Subset of Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

If I have an array with 12 elements and I want a new array with that drops the first and 12th elements.  For example, if my array looks like this:

```
__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
```

I want to either transform it or create a new array that looks like

```
__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __

b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k 
__ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __ __
```

I know I can do it by iterating over them.  I was just wondering if there was a cleaner way built into C#.

Comment: Isn't "j" the 10th element in the array though?  Or did you mean first and last elements?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

LINQ is your friend. :)

```
var newArray = oldArray.Skip(1).Take(oldArray.Length - 2).ToArray();
```

Somewhat less efficient than manually creating the array and iterating over it of course, but far simple...

The slightly lengithier method that uses [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) is the following.

```
var newArray = new int[oldArray.Count - 2];
Array.Copy(oldArray, 1, newArray, 0, newArray.Length);
```

Comment: I really liked your original answer.  LINQ has been my friend for sometime.  I'd just never used skip and take.  Thanks.

Comment: @L. Moser: No problem - changed back too. :) And yeah, I think I discover a new useful LINQ method every week or so.

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler if you did the `Skip` after the `Take`? Like: `oldArray.Take(oldArray.Length - 1).Skip(1).ToArray()`? Either way are likely equal in effeciency.

Comment: Not a good application of LINQ. If you're already down at the char array level then do it right.

Answer (score 40):

Linq is all nice and snazzy, but if you're looking for a 1-liner you could just throw together your own utility functions:

```
static class ArrayUtilities
{
    // create a subset from a range of indices
    public static T[] RangeSubset<T>(this T[] array, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        T[] subset = new T[length];
        Array.Copy(array, startIndex, subset, 0, length);
        return subset;
    }

    // create a subset from a specific list of indices
    public static T[] Subset<T>(this T[] array, params int[] indices)
    {
        T[] subset = new T[indices.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
        {
            subset[i] = array[indices[i]];
        }
        return subset;
    }
}
```

So then you could do the following:

```
        char[] original = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' };

        // array containing 'b' - 'f'
        char[] rangeSubset = original.RangeSubset(1, original.Length - 2);

        // array containing 'c', 'd', and 'f'
        char[] specificSubset = original.Subset(2, 3, 5);
```

Answer (score 28):

[C# 8 has a `Range` and `Index` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

```
char[] a = { 'a', 'b', 'c',  'd',  'e',  'f',  'g',  'h',  'i',  'j',  'k',  'l' };
Index i1 = 1;  // number 1 from beginning
Index i2 = ^1; // number 1 from end
var slice = a[i1..i2]; // { 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j' }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ArraySegment<T>` structure like below:

```
var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var offset = 1;
var count = 2;
var subset = new ArraySegment<int>(arr, offset, count)
             .ToArray(); // output: { 2, 3 }
```

Check here for an [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44464131/450913) that makes use of it even easier.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy(VS.71).aspx) or LINQ.

```
var letters = string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };

int length = letters.Length - 2;
var items = new string[length];
Array.Copy(letters, 1, items, 0, length);
// or
var items = letters.Skip(1).Take(length).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Array.Copy() will do that for you, but you still have to create your new array with its correct size.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] s = initialize the array...

var subset = s.Skip(1).Take(s.Length - 2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid manually indexing the array. Don't try to pull request that anywhere though:

```
var newArray = oldArray.Skip(1).Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray()
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to drop the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ReadOnlySpan` struct the code of the `substr` for array may look like following:

```cs
var subArray = input.AsSpan(offset, length).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ has proved to be extremely slow regarding demanding operations in my tests.
Array.Copy as shown in the accepted answer is much faster.
however, the fastest method so far to achieve your goal is by doing this:

```
var sub = input[startIndex..endIndex];
```

(note that there are two dots between the start and end index)

I don't know why no one talks about this feature, please tell me if there is something wrong with this method.