# Convert piece of code from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++

i'm trying to convert code from c++ to c#.. but i'm stuck.
Can somebody let me know where i'm wrong?

C++ code is:

```
void CALLBACK Test(void *buffer, DWORD length)
{
  BYTE *b=(BYTE*)buffer, temp[20000];
  DWORD p=0;
  while (p<length) 
  {
    DWORD c=min(length-p, sizeof(temp));
    memcpy(temp, b+p, c);
    c=SendData(dummy, temp, c);
    if (c==-1) break;
    p+=c;
  }
}

where is SendData(int, byte[], int)
```

And current c# code

```
void Test(IntPtr buffer, int length)
{

        byte[] temp = new byte[20000];
        byte[] b = new byte[length];
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, b, 0, length);

   long p=0;
   while (p<length) 
   {
    long c=Math.Min(length-p, 20000);
    Array.Copy(temp, b+p, c);
    c=SendData(dummy, temp, (int)c);
    if (c==-1) break;
    p+=c;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure did I did it correctly, but I can see I cannot apply operator `+` to `b+s` because it's `long` and `byte[]`.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of doing a "literal" conversion, don't you think it's better to look at what the function does and re-make that in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the 5-arg version of Array.Copy, which lets you pass offsets into both the start and destination arrays.  This is the more "C#" way of doing things as opposed to pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you may add a DWORD (an int, really) to a pointer and the compiler knows to offset the address of the pointer by the specified amount. C# doesn't let you do that, normally. (There is a way to do pointer arithmetic in C#, but don't.) So, in the C# version, you need another way to copy at offset `p` relative to the start of `b`. One of the overloads of [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) will let you do that. Something like:

```
Array.Copy(temp, 0, b, p, c);
```

Comment: Nothing against pointers in C#, when you know what you are doing you can speed up code sometimes a lot and translate C++ code into C# code. ( e.g. image processing, image loading,... ) Of course you should really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at: [How to split a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797/how-to-split-a-byte-array), because that is in effect what you are trying to accomplish with the `b+p`portion.