# splitting array of byte with subarray using c# LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, indexing, split

I'm experiencing a problem of further kind:

I have an array like {0xNN, 0xNN, 0xNN, 0xNN, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xNN, 0xNN, 0xFF, 0xFF} where {0xFF, 0xFF} is a delimeter.

Is it possible to get an enumaration like {{0xNN, 0xNN, 0xNN, 0xNN} , {0xNN, 0xNN}} by using LINQ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797/how-to-split-a-byte-array)

Comment: @Mike That q's talking about a type of substring, not split.

Comment: @Mike Cant see LINQ or any other kind of lambdas there.

Comment: @IceCroft: if your question is simply "is it possible", then the answer is Yes. Perhaps you should show some code or context so that we may understand why this is restricted to "LINQ" (or please describe what you think LINQ is, because LINQ has nothing to do with lambda methods).

Comment: @sixlettervariables agreed, ofc its possible with just linq but, it would be difficult to avoid lots of pointless reiteration.

Comment: I'm sure some variation on Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm will yield the fastest possible performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension like this, to do the job in one pass with any length of delimiter.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEnumerable<T> delimiter)
    {
       var delimiterList = delimiter.ToList();
       var outputBuffer = new List<T>();
       var m = 0;

       foreach(var item in source)
       {
           if item.Equals(delimiterList[m])
           {
               m++;

               if(m == delimiterList.Count)
               {
                  m = 0;

                  if (outputBuffer.Count > 0)
                  {
                      yield return outputBuffer;
                      outputBuffer = new List<T>();
                  }
               }
           }
           else
           {
               outputBuffer.AddRange(delimiterList.Take(m));

               if (item.Equals(delimiterList[0]))
               {
                   m = 1;
               }
               else
               {
                   m = 0;
                   outputBuffer.Add(item);
               }
           }              
       }

       outputBuffer.AddRange(delimiterList.Take(m)); 

       if (outputBuffer.Count > 0)
       {
           yield return outputBuffer;
       }
   }
}
```

Which you could use like this.

```
var joinedBytes = new byte[] { ... }
var delimiter = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xFF }

var splitBytes = joinedBytes.Split(delimiter);
```

Comment: @Akli, another good fix that got rejected. I've integrated your suggestion with a slight tweak.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do it in LINQ, because your delimiter is defined by two elements of the collection.