# LINQ to get sub-array

Tags: c#, linq, substring

I have a `byte[]` and I want to extract a portion of the array and convert it to a string.  I want to use LINQ and to do it in one line.  This was the best I could find, but it fails me.

```
String id = new String(payload.Skip(60).Take(92-60+1).ToString());
```

to extract payload[60] to payload[92] and convert it to a string.  Is there a better way?  And I'm getting some errors with this syntax still..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797/how-to-split-a-byte-array

Comment: What does the byte array represent? How do you want it converted to a string? Can you provide example inputs and output?

Comment: I'm assuming the person wants to actually convert the bytes back to a string - as in `Encoding.GetString(byte[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No linq is necessary. [ASCIIEncoding.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8.aspx)

```
var str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(payload, 60, 92-60+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like following:

```
string.Concat((object[])payload.Skip(60).Take(92-60+1).Cast<object>().ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String id =Encoding.ASCII.GetString(payload.ToArray().Skip(60).Take(92-60+1).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a UTF8 encoded string, you could use linq like so:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.Skip(60).Take(32).ToArray());
```

A more straightforward and efficient solution is this:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 60, 32);
```

This avoids copying the section of the array, and a quick check with the stopwatch shows it is 20 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use some encoding to convert your byte array to string (in my opinion this is safe way compare to other approach for byte array to string) and this encoding is depend to your byte array format and you know it better.

Second, because you have an array, it's better to use built-in array function like [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx), because this is faster than linq also you don't need to traverse 92 elements of array, you just need traverse 33 elements.

```
var secondArray = new byte[92-60+1];
Array.Copy(payLoad, 60, secondArray, 0, 92-60+1);
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
string result = encodin.GetString(secondArray);
```