# Divide array into N chunks

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I have `byte[]` and I want to split this into several parts, I am using this solution:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>> Chunk(byte[] list, int chunkSize)
        {
            int i = 0;
            var chunks = from name in list
                         group name by i++ / chunkSize into part
                         select part.AsEnumerable();
            return chunks;
        }
```

For example I have `Array` with size of 880 bytes and I am calling this way: `Chunk(MyArray, 3)`
So this divided my `Array` into several pieces with max 3 bytes while I want to split my `Array` into 3 pieces.
What do I need to change in my function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797/how-to-split-a-byte-array)

Comment: Suppose there are four items in the array, just to make the example small. Say `{A, B, C, D}`.  What is the solution you want?  `{A, B}, {C}, {D}`, or `{A}, {B}, {C, D}` or, as Tim Schmelter's solution suggests, `{A, D}, {B}, {C}` are all possibilities. You have underspecified your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%` instead of `/`

```
 var chunks = from name in list
     group name by i++ % chunkSize into part
     select part.AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Suppose the items are A, B, C, D. This makes groups { A, D }, { B } , { C }. Is that really what the OP wants?